# How do we set the url in the img element,if the the files are present in the assets folder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

The assets folder consists of many images which are to be printed in the view according to the list elements.
For eg:
 what can be the question mark be filled with in order to retrieve the images from the image folder.
My code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let data of datas | async" class="pqr">
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img src= {{"../assets/image/" + data.imageName}}>
      </ion-thumbnail>
      {{data.Comp}}<br> 
      {{data.Demand}}<br>
      <p> {{data.Desig}}<br></p>
        {{data.Place}}<br>
        {{data.when}}<br>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code here?

Comment: @Sampath I have shown my code.The Assets folder consists of image files which I want to be printed in the view corresponding to the items in the data.Please help me.Thank you

Comment: And also can you share the code where how to get the `datas`? Is that `observable` or?

Comment: Yes, it is an observable.Async data.

Comment: can you share that code also?

Comment: `datas:` `FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;` 
`constructor(public navCtrl:` `NavController,public` `authData:AuthData,public` `af:AngularFire){` `this.datas=af.database.list('/datas')`
This datas is a reference node in firebase,which conains the json data.But I think this won't affect that thing.

Comment: @Sampath, I have shared the code.

Comment: Please see the **Update** section.see whether `this.datas` is having data.You can debug now.

Comment: @Sampath this.data gets the JSON object which I have stored manually in the firebase database.This is correctly getting displayed in the view.

Comment: Typescript error:`Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'`
Removed [] also but the same error is diplayed with `Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we set the url of the img element to print the view with the images.Below is my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989733/how-can-we-set-the-url-of-the-img-element-to-print-the-view-with-the-images-belo)

Comment: yes, it is the same one@sebaferreras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Please try as shown below.`subscribe` inside the `.ts` file and remove `async` pipe.Also, put `*ngFor` on the `<ion-list>` element.Just try this and see whether it has any different outcome.

*.ts*

```
datas: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>; 

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public authData:AuthData,public af:AngularFire){ 
   af.database.list('/datas').subscribe(
      result => {
        this.datas = result;
      },
}
```

*.html*

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let data of datas">
    <ion-item  class="pqr">
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img src= <img src= "../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      {{data.Comp}}<br> 
      {{data.Demand}}<br>
      <p> {{data.Desig}}<br></p>
        {{data.Place}}<br>
        {{data.when}}<br>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**Old**

You have to do it as shown below.

```
<ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img src= "../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}">
</ion-thumbnail>
```

Comment: It is still not working.
<ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img src= "../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>

Comment: Actually, in my assets folder, there is a folder named image, which contains image files.I want to display the images corresponding to the items list(data).So, I need to write the URL in the image's element tag.
I am unable to write the URL.I have also tried the code that you shared,but it is also not working. @Sampath

Comment: Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: When I checked the response it displays:
Cannot GET /assets/image/

Comment: as a test try to do like this : `<img src= "../assets/image/yourimage.png">` give a hard coded image name and remove the loop from the view.see that it is working?

Comment: maybe you can keep the loop.no problem about it.

Comment: But, the same image gets displayed in the list items, which is not needed.

Comment: You have to give as list type like this `FirebaseListObservable<Item[]>`

Comment: I have give the same that you have told but the error is like Error: `Cannot find name Item`

Comment: I just gave it as an example.You have to create a class like `Item` before using it as a data type.

Comment: @Sampath.Trying this, but the result is not displaying.

Comment: any errors? can you share the final code changes too?

Comment: I have solved the issue. thanks @Sampath for your kind efforts:)

Comment: I have not provided the url in the database for imageName.now it is fetching images with `data.imageName`.