# How can we set the url of the img element to print the view with the images.Below is my code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

The assets folder consists of many images which are to be printed in the view according to the list elements. 
My code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let data of datas | async" class="pqr">
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img src= {{"../assets/image/" + data.imageName}}>
      </ion-thumbnail>
      {{data.Comp}}<br> 
      {{data.Demand}}<br>
      <p> {{data.Desig}}<br></p>
        {{data.Place}}<br>
        {{data.when}}<br>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: `<img src={{"../assets/image/" + data.imageName}}>`
I want to add the images in the list items which are present in the assets folder.Therefore, I need to put the correct URL in the image element tag in order to print the images in the corresponding items in the view. @meyer9

Comment: Use `ng-src="../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}"`

Comment: My application is not working when I am using `<img ng-src= "../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}">`.@meyer9

Comment: Look at the DOM by using F12 or Cmd+Alt+I and check what the images src's are getting set to. Make sure that looks OK. If it's something like undefined, you know the variable is not getting passed into the `$scope`.

Comment: By using F12 in the console-> networks, it shows that no response for the image.But the application is not working by using ng-src.

Comment: go to the DOM and check the actual image source

Comment: Actual image source is correct, when I am using `<img src= "../assets/image/image.png>` it works very fine, but the problem is all the list elements gets the same image, I want the different image to the corresponding list items from my assets folder.

Comment: Try `<img [src]="../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}"/>` Also are you sure `data.imageName` is getting the correct name and extension? It is clearly not getting the file. `./assets/image/name.png` works for me..

Comment: Tried `<img [src]="../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}"/>` app isn't working for me with this code.
When tried data.imageName, in the network it shows cannot get response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DomSanitizer`.

```
// Angular
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

@Component({...})
export class YourPage {

    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, ...) { 

        //...
    }

    public getImageUrl(data: any): any {
        let url = `../assets/image/${data.imageName}`;
        return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url); 
    }
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<!-- ... -->
<ion-item *ngFor="let data of datas | async" class="pqr">
    <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img *ngIf="data && data.imageName" [src]="getImageUrl(data)">
    </ion-thumbnail>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: @sebaferreras.If have tried the above piece of code that you shared.But it is displaying error in the console as:`GET http://localhost:8100/assets/image/undefined 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: So your `data.imageName` is undefined for some reason... could you please check if the name of the property is the right one?

Comment: I've added an ngIf now to avoid that error... please check if  `<img *ngIf="data && data.imageName" [src]="getImageUrl(data)">` works

Comment: Now the Error is not reflecting but the thumbnails are also not been displayed.
Yes the name of the property is correct.If I give `"../assets/image/imagename.png"` it gets displayed to all the items.But I need different images that are present in assets folder for different items.

Comment: Check in the console if there is any error or warning. Inspect the image element to see if it's already in the DOM, maybe we just need to add a few css rules to modify it's width and height

Comment: `Cannot GET /assets/image/`
This error 404 not found is displayed in the console, when I gave `../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}`

Comment: `../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}` is not what I've posted in the answer

Comment: Edited the comment.sorry

Comment: My Html file:
`<ion-item *ngFor="let data of datas | async" class="pqr">
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
       <!-- <img src= "../assets/image/{{data.imageName}}">-->
       <img *ngIf="data && data.imageName" [src]="getImageUrl(data)">
      </ion-thumbnail>`

Comment: Also while logging out : `Runtime Error
Converting circular structure to JSON`
Error is displayed.

Comment: does the `data.imageName` property also include the extension of the file? The circular structure error is not related to this issue.

Comment: yes the file name have different extensions such as .png , .jpg etc.

Comment: I have solved the issue...:) thanks @sebaferreras for you efforts

Comment: Glad to hear that :) If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so we can close it

Comment: Actually, I have not provided the image url in the database from which I am fetching it with `data.imageName`.